# What do "21B.19" and "25A.162A" mean in these references in an Oxford book list?

Tags: citations

I don't understand the part which says `21B.19` in first book reference and `25A.162A` in second book reference. I checked both books; they have page numbers and there are no sections which has alphabetical naming (`A` or `B` or such letter).

> Cox, PA (1989) The Elements: Their Origin, Abundance, and Distribution
> – 21B.19

> Langmuir, C.H. & Broecker, W. (2012) How to build a habitable planet.
> Princeton University Press - 25A.162A

Link to syllabus: https://www.earth.ox.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Earth-Sciences-Undergraduate-Handbook-2020-21-DRAFT-v1.5.pdf

How should I understand these notations?

Comment: Out of curiosity: did you check the paper copies of these books? If yes, what were the shelfmarks of the library shelves where they were located? (If you don't have direct access to the shelves due to the Covid-19 pandemic, can you ask a librarian?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems these are shelfmarks in Oxford's Earth Science Library. Search for the books in Oxford's [SOLO](http://solo.bodleian.ox.ac.uk) library system and you will find the books and their shelfmarks.

[image]

Comment: I searched SOLO but I didn't find the codes "21B.19" or "25A.162A" for these books. Could you please add a screenshot of what you found?

Comment: Where do you see the current shelfmark? That page lists the old ones (e.g. QE 515 BRO) but when I search that page for the current one (or a substring of it, "162A"), I find nothing.

Answer (score 2):

At the top of page 25 of the document linked in the question, the instructions say:

> Books used in each lecture course may be ranked as: Essential (***); Useful (**); Supplementary (*). Numbers in **bold type** indicate the shelf-mark of each book. There should be a reference copy of each title in the “Confined Cupboard”. Loan copies will also usually be available and will have the same shelf location. (Check the online catalogue – **OLIS** – for copies in other libraries). It is easy to recall books that are out on loan by emailing the librarian.

So these are the shelf-marks, and if you are on campus, you can find a reference copy in the "Confined Cupboard."